# EJB call is missing caller principal when used inside a Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lambda, wildfly

I'm trying to call a bean API from inside a lambda expression, but the `SessionContext` of it does not contain the correct `caller principal`. It is `anonymous` instead.

Even the interceptors on this API behave the same way.

Only happens when the bean is called from inside the lambda. Couldn't find any other questions on this topic.

I'm using WildFly 10.0.0, Hibernate Core 5.0.10 (JPA 2.1)

Comment: Show a bit code. How the lambda looks like? Is it parallel stream i.e.? Before then lambda executed do you have right principal. i.e. add @RolesAllowed  annotation to method and see it can be executed before than call of lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Running in a lambda in your case probably means that the code is executed in a different thread, and because security context is usually bound to a thread, when you run an asynchronous task in a new thread, it won't inherit the security context from the parent. That means that the new thread will have to re-authenticate in some way. For WildFly 10, this should work if you add this to your lambda:

```
org.jboss.security.client.SecurityClient client = SecurityClientFactory.getSecurityClient();
client.setSimple("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
client.login();
try {
   bean.call();
} finally {
   client.logout();
}
```

if you switch to WildFly 11 with Elytron, this will be available:

```
final SecurityIdentity identity = org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityDomain.getCurrent().getCurrentSecurityIdentity();
identity.runAs(() -> { the-code-you-want-to-run-with-this-identity } );
```